# How to search a value in the middle of excel for a changing value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to create a formula in excel to find a file path value. an example is:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\x1234_namezo_ect.ext
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\x1235_nameon_ect.ext
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\x1233_nametw_ect.ext
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\x1237_namethr_ect.ext
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\x1240_namefour_ect.ext
```

I am looking to get the x1234,x1235 ect. The length to the value will change over time and the file name is not always the same length. The only thing that will stay the same is the length of the x####.

Is there a formula that can be flexible and be able to find the x#### regardless of the length of either side?

Comment: Does the file path always begin with the same `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\`?

Comment: Yes, there is.  What have you found in your research? On the worksheet, `SEARCH`; in VBA, probably need to create a loop and use `InStr`, or use `Regular Expressions`

Comment: no sometimes it will have one more subfolder

Comment: I think i found the answer through trial and error, it requires left,right,len,and search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use a `UDF` to extract:

- **Everything** after the **LAST** instance of `\`
- **Excluding** the last **4** characters of the string *(presumably the extension)*
- *Assumes every input has a 4 digit extension in format of `.###`*

---

```
Function FILENAME(Target As String) As String

temp = Split(Target, "\")
temp = temp(UBound(temp))

FILENAME = Left(temp, Len(temp) - 4)

End Function
```

---

Place the code inside a `Module` and then you can call this function directly from the worksheet with `=FILENAME(A1)`. Notice that this will also work if your file name has `.` inside the string *(see second example in photo)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer through trial and error:

```
=left(right(A1,Len(A1)-search("\x",A1)),6)
```

This looks for the \x and gets the next 4 (6 adding the \x) text after.